# Gradle - how to specify javadoc location jar file for maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, eclipselink, gradle

I want to add local javadoc jar to maven dependency. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it? The problem is that I've got maven dependency which contains transitive jars

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.5.0'
}
```

`gradle dependencies` command returned this:

```
compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.5.0
     +--- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.0
     \--- org.eclipse.persistence:commonj.sdo:2.1.1
```

Main dependency `eclipselink` contains javadoc for `javax.persistence` so I can't see javadoc hints in eclipse editor. What I want to do is to connect `eclipselink` javadoc to `javax.persistence`.

This is what I expect:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.0' {
        javadoc = <path to javadoc>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. I've edited eclipse `.classpath` file using gradle `eclipse` plugin and it do what it should. This is the code:

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
       downloadSources=true
       downloadJavadoc=true
        file {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                // find eclipselink javadoc path
                def eclipselinkPath = configurations.compile.find { it.absolutePath.contains('eclipselink') }
                def javaxPersistenceJavadocPath = ""
                node.each {
                    def filePath = it.attribute('path')
                    if (file(filePath) == file(eclipselinkPath)) {
                        javaxPersistenceJavadocPath = it.attributes.attribute.@value[0]
                    }
                }
                // add eclipselink javadoc path as attribute to javax.persistence
                def javaxPersistencePath = configurations.compile.find { it.absolutePath.contains('javax.persistence') }
                node.each {
                    def filePath = it.attribute('path')
                    if (file(filePath) == file(javaxPersistencePath)) {
                        it.appendNode('attributes').appendNode('attribute', [name:'javadoc_location', value:javaxPersistenceJavadocPath])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that it looks ugly but I didn't have more time to fight with that problem. BTW it wasn't the source of my problem (I've got problem with dependencies or gradle cache, I don't know yet).